# Trying to read a directory created by node js after execution of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a node application which does is that it scraps google and downloads top 15 images and then store it in HDD in a folder which is the query received after compressing. Now problem that I'm facing is When I'm going back to read that folder using readdirSync and storing the results in error, it returns an empty array, what is wrong with the code.

```
 request(url, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error) {
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var imgNodes = $('#ires td a img');
    // imgNodes is merely an array-like object, sigh.
    // This is purposedly old-school JS because newer stuff doesn't work:
    var urls = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= 14; i++){
        let imgNode = imgNodes[i];
        urls.push(imgNode.attribs['src']);
    }  
// console.log(urls);

const processCompress = new Promise(resolve => {
    fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname,'Photos',query), function (error) {
    let j = 0;
     if(!error){
        for(i in urls){
            console.log(i);
            var source = tinify.fromUrl(urls[i]);
            source.toFile(path.join(__dirname,'Photos', query,"optimized_"+ ++j +".jpg"));
        }
    }});
    resolve();
});

const getFiles = new Promise(resolve => {
    fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname,'Photos', query)).forEach(function (file) {
        fileName.push(path.join(__dirname,'Photos',query,file));
    });
    resolve();
});

function colourMeBw(){
    for(let k = 0; k < fileName.length; k++){
    Jimp.read(fileName[k], (err, image) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        image.greyscale().write(fileName[k]);
    });
}}
processCompress.then(() => getFiles);
colourMeBw(); 
 } else {
console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
 }
```

Comment: You received a number of answers here and never provided any feedback on any of them.  That's not really how this site works.  Please evaluate the answers you received and ask questions if you have any or accept the best answer if your question is answered.  This is meant to be an interactive site.  You ask a question, we provide answers, you provide feedback on the answers and hopefully eventually accept one (by clicking the checkmark next to it) when your question is answered.  Asking a question and then disappearing with zero feedback is NOT how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your code:

1. In `processCompress()`, you are resolving the promise before `fs.mkdir()` is done and before any of the images have been fetched and written.
2. In `getFiles()` you are wrapping a synchronous I/O function in a promise. The first problem is that you shouldn't be using synchronous I/O at all.  That is the fastest way to wreck the scalability of your server.  Then, once you switch to the async version of `fs.readdir()`, you have to resolve the promise appropriately.
3. There's no way to know when `colourMeBw()` is actually done.
4. You should never iterate an array with `for(i in urls)` for a variety of reasons.  In ES6, you can use `for (url of urls)`.  In ES5, you can use either a traditional `for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {}` or `urls.forEach()`.
5. You have no error propagation.  The whole process would choke if you got an error in the middle somewhere because later parts of the process would still continue to try to do their work even though things have already failed.  There's no way for the caller to know what errors happened.
6. There's no way to know when everything is done.

Here's a version of your code that uses promises to properly sequence things, propagate all errors appropriately and tell you when everything is done.  I don't myself know the `tinify` and `Jimp` libraries so I consulted their documentation to see how to use them with promises (both appear to have promise support built-in).  I used the Bluebird promise library to give me promise support for the `fs` library and to take advantage of `Promise.map()` which is convenient here.

If you didn't want to use the Bluebird promise library, you could promisify the `fs` module other ways or event promisify individual `fs` methods you want to use with promises.  But once you get used to doing async programming with promises, you're going to want to use it for all your `fs` work.

This is obviously untested (no way to run this here), but hopefully you get the general idea for what we're trying to do.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
const Jimp = require('jimp');
const rp = require('request-promise');

rp(url).then(function(body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var imgNodes = $('#ires td a img');
    // imgNodes is merely an array-like object, sigh.
    // This is purposedly old-school JS because newer stuff doesn't work:
    var urls = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
        let imgNode = imgNodes[i];
        urls.push(imgNode.attribs['src']);
    }
    // console.log(urls);

    const processCompress = function() {
        return fs.mkdirAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'Photos', query).then(function(error) {
            let j = 0;
            return Promise.map(urls, function(url) {
                var source = tinify.fromUrl(url);
                return source.toFile(path.join(__dirname, 'Photos', query, "optimized_" + ++j + ".jpg"));
            });
        });
    });

    const getFiles = function() {
        return fs.readdirAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'Photos', query).then(function(files) {
            return files.map(function(file) {
                return path.join(__dirname, 'Photos', query, file);
            });
        });
    };

    function colourMeBw(fileList) {
        return Promise.map(fileList, function(file) {
            return Jimp.read(file).greyscale().write(file);
        });
    }
    return processCompress().then(getFiles).then(colourMeBw);
}).then(function() {
    // all done here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Your `query` variable in use here does not appear to be defined anywhere so I am assuming it is defined in a higher scope.

Note that one big advantage of using promises for a multi-stage operation like this is that all errors end up on one single place, no matter where they occurred in the overall multi-level process.

---

Note: If you are processing a large number of images or a medium number of large images, this could end up using a fair amount of memory because this code processes all the images in parallel.  One of the advantages of Bluebird's `Promise.map()` is that is has an optional `concurrency` option that specifies how many of the requests should be "in-flight" at once.  You can dial that down to a medium number to control memory usage if necessary.

Or, you could change the structure so that rather than compress all, then convert all to greyscale, you could compress one, convert it grey scale, then move on to the next, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the resolve() call directly after fs.mkdir is wrong, because mkdir is working asnyc, so the resolve is reached without performing the whole work of mkdir.

```
const processCompress = new Promise(resolve => {
            fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'Photos', query), function(error) {
                let j = 0;
                if (!error) {
                    for (i in urls) {
                        console.log(i);
                        var source = tinify.fromUrl(urls[i]);
                        source.toFile(path.join(__dirname, 'Photos', query, "optimized_" + ++j + ".jpg"));
                    }
                }

                resolve(); // <---- inside callback from mkdir.
            });
            // call the resolve from inside the mkDirs-callback function
            // resolve();
        });
```

I hope that will fix your problem.

Comment: I liked your first sentence that explains a core problem.  But, ripping out promises is moving backwards in programming life.

Comment: @jfriend00  You are right on using promises, so I edit my post and remove the async npm part.

Comment: Your proposed answer is only one small part of what needs fixing here.

Answer (score 0):

I read the code and I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const tinify = require("tinify");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const getImages = url => {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(responseToText)
    .then(bodyToImageUrls)
    .then(makePhotoDirectory)
    .then(downloadFiles)
    .then(processImageData)
    .then(doImageManipulation)
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
    });
};

const responseToText = res => res.text();

const bodyToImageUrls = body => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  return $("img").attr("src");
};

const imgNodesToUrls = imgNodes => {
  return imgNodes.map(imgNode => imgNode.name);
};

const makePhotoDirectory = urls => {
  const dir = path.join(__dirname, "Photos");

  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }

  return urls;
};

const downloadFiles = urls => {
  /* 
    I could not run this since I don't have a Tinify API key
    but I assume that it returns a promise.
  */
  const promises = urls.map(url => tinify.fromUrl(url));
  return Promise.all(promises);
};

const processImageData = imageData => {
  const promises = imageData.map((data, i) => {
    const fileUrl = path.join(__dirname, "Photos", `optimized_${i}.jpg`);
    return data.toFile(fileUrl);
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
};

const doImageManipulation = images => {
  // Add your image manipulation here
};
```